# Investment question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Jack invests \$1000 at a certain annual interest rate, and he invests another \$3000 at an annual rate that is one-half percent higher. If he receives a total of \$135 interest in 1 year, at what rate is the \$1000 invested?

No idea how to solve this. I tried using the interest formula ($135=1000*1*r$) which simplified to $r=13.5$ but that was obviously wrong. Tried a few other things but nothing close enough, and I can't find any examples of this in my book. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Like $1000\cdot\frac{r\%}{100\%}+3000\cdot\frac{(r+1/2)\%}{100\%}=135$ ?

Comment: I don't understand.. can you explain?

Comment: I GOT IT. I GOT 3 PERCENT.